# AMD Codexl profiling: Opencl Memory leak detected [Ref =1] Object created by clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: memory-leaks, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I have no idea why I keep getting this warning as I've gone through the code numerous times and I can't figure out where this is coming from as I'm pretty sure (but clearly not) releasing all the memory. Hopefully someone who knows more than I can take a look at my code and point out where and why this is happening.

Thanks!

```
int runKernel( Image *anImage, 
              PixelPacket *imagePixels, 
              MagickSizeType imageSizeBytes, 
              const char *kernelSource )
{

    cl_context myContext ;
    cl_command_queue myQueue ;
    cl_mem *outputImage ;
    cl_event clEvent ;
    int bitsPerChannel = anImage[0].depth ; 
    int width = anImage[0].columns ;
    int height = anImage[0].rows ;



    /****************************
    Setup the Opencl environment
    ****************************/


    // Use this to check the output of each API call
    cl_int status ;

    // Retrieve the number of platforms
    cl_uint numPlatforms = 0 ;
    status = clGetPlatformIDs( 0, NULL, &numPlatforms ) ;

    // Allocate enough space for each platform
    cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL ;
    platforms = (cl_platform_id *) malloc( numPlatforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id) ) ;

    // Fill in the platforms
    status = clGetPlatformIDs( numPlatforms, platforms, NULL ) ;

    // Retrieve the number of devices for the 1st platform
    cl_uint numDevices = 0 ;
    status = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &numDevices ) ;

    // Allocate enough space for each device
    cl_device_id *devices ;
    devices = (cl_device_id *) malloc( numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id) ) ;

    // Fill in the devices
    status = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numDevices, 
                devices, NULL ) ;

    // Create the context
    myContext = clCreateContext( NULL, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, &status ) ;

    // Create the command queue with the 1st device
    myQueue = clCreateCommandQueue( myContext, devices[0], 0, &status ) ;



    /****************************
    Create Images and Move Data
    ****************************/



    // Set format and descriptor to proper values according to image type
    cl_image_format *image_format = NULL ;
    cl_image_desc *image_desc = NULL ;
    get_cl_image_format( anImage, &image_desc, &image_format ) ;

    // Create the image sampler
    cl_sampler clSampler = clCreateSampler(
                            myContext,
                            CL_FALSE, //use pixel based addressing not normalized
                            CL_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, // set equal to the pixel at the edge of the image
                            CL_FILTER_NEAREST, 
                            &status);

    // Set input Image region parameters
    size_t origin[3] = {0, 0, 0} ; // Offset within the image to copy from
    size_t region[3] = {width, height, 1} ; // Elements per dimension for 2d image 


    // Create cl memory object for the input image
    cl_mem_flags flagsRead = CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR ;

    cl_mem clInput = clCreateImage( myContext, flagsRead, 
                                ( const cl_image_format *)image_format, 
                                ( const cl_image_desc *)image_desc, 
                                imagePixels, 
                                &status ) ;


    // Allocate space for output image and create cl memory object 
    float *outputPixels =  (float *) malloc( imageSizeBytes ) ;
    cl_mem_flags flagsWrite = CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR ;

    cl_mem clOutput = clCreateImage( myContext, flagsWrite, 
                                    (const cl_image_format *)image_format, 
                                    ( const cl_image_desc *)image_desc, 
                                    outputPixels, 
                                    &status ) ;


    //Copy input image to the device
    status = clEnqueueWriteImage( myQueue, clInput, CL_FALSE, origin, region,
                                0, 0, imagePixels, 0, NULL, NULL ) ;



    /*****************************
    Compile the kernel from source
    *****************************/



    // kernelSource stores the kernel code and must be NULL terminated
    cl_program myProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource( myContext, 1, 
                                                    &kernelSource, 
                                                    NULL, 
                                                    &status ) ;

    // Compile the program  
    const char buildOptions[] = "-cl-std=CL1.2 -cl-mad-enable\0";
    status = clBuildProgram( myProgram, 1, devices, buildOptions, NULL, NULL ) ;

    // Create the kernel
    cl_kernel myKernel = clCreateKernel( myProgram, "convolution", &status ) ;



    /**********************************
    Set kernel args and run the program
    **********************************/



    // Set the kernel arguments

    clSetKernelArg( myKernel, 0, sizeof( cl_mem ), &clInput ) ;
    clSetKernelArg( myKernel, 1, sizeof( cl_mem ), &clOutput ) ;
    clSetKernelArg( myKernel, 2, sizeof( int ), &height ) ;
    clSetKernelArg( myKernel, 3, sizeof( int ), &width ) ;
    clSetKernelArg( myKernel, 4, sizeof( cl_sampler ), &clSampler ) ;

    //Execute the kernel
    status = clEnqueueTask( myQueue, myKernel, 0, NULL, NULL ) ;

    //Read the output buffer back to the host
    status = clEnqueueReadImage( myQueue, clOutput, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, 
                               (void *) outputPixels, 0, NULL, &clEvent ) ;



    /**********************************
    Free Resources
    **********************************/



    /* Wait for the kernel to finish */ 
    clWaitForEvents( 1, &clEvent ) ;

    free( refImage ) ;
    free( platforms ) ;
    free( devices ) ;
    free( outputPixels ) ;
    free( image_desc ) ;
    free( image_format ) ;

    clReleaseSampler( clSampler ) ;
    clReleaseMemObject( clInput ) ;
    clReleaseMemObject( clOutput ) ;    
    clReleaseProgram( myProgram ) ;
    clReleaseCommandQueue( myQueue ) ;
    clReleaseKernel( myKernel ) ;   
    clReleaseContext( myContext ) ; 
    clReleaseEvent( clEvent ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your error message indicates that the memory leak occurs in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.  Unless I'm blind, the closest you get is clEnqueueTask, which may be calling clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.  After making the correction proposed by tim, please comment out the clEnqueueTask line and see if the memory leak is still present.  If it is not present then I suspect that a cl_event object is being created in clEnqueueTask, even though you pass NULL for the return event.

Comment: Hey Chippies seems you're right! I added the clEvent in place of the NULL and released it right after and it solves the leak. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if that constitutes a bug in the driver?  What you did was totally correct.  It was clEnqueueTask leaking the event, not you.

Comment: @Tim I agree.  My understanding of the specs is that all functions shall not create an event when passing NULL for the event parameter.  For future reference, the OP has posted this on AMD's developer forums at [http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/168582](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/168582).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that destroying the queue, kernel, context, or program before releasing the event (`clEvent`) is causing the warning.  You might try the following:

```
clReleaseEvent( clEvent ) ; // <<< THIS ONE FIRST
clReleaseSampler( clSampler ) ;
clReleaseMemObject( clInput ) ;
clReleaseMemObject( clOutput ) ;    
clReleaseProgram( myProgram ) ;
clReleaseCommandQueue( myQueue ) ;
clReleaseKernel( myKernel ) ;   
clReleaseContext( myContext ) ;
```

Alternately, debug the release ops line by line until you get the warning.

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried that but it had no effect. The order doesn't seem to matter as I tried it at the end once and it still shows the same thing, but thanks for the trying!

Comment: I am not sure what the CL spec says, but in general it might be a good idea to be sensitive to the order of destruction if you run this on other implementations.  Kudos to the AMD implementation for permitting any order of destruction though!

Comment: The clRelease* functions decrement a reference counter.  Once that counter reaches 0 and any objects attached to the object being released have been deleted then the object gets deleted.  A properly written implementation should then internally sort out the order in which objects get deleted, irrespective of the order in which you release them, with the restriction that you must release them before they can be deleted.